# Creating RadioButtons with a loop but problem with them having the same value

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make an exam sheet with "n" 4-option questions.
I have created "n" sets of 4 horizontal `Radiobutton`s with a loop.
the problem is everytime a certain radio button is selected, all other sets' radio buttons will also switch to that value.
e.g.: For question 1 when option 4 (with `value=4`) is selected all other sets' `Radiobutton`s will switch to option 4. I think this is due to them having the same value.

How do you make them not all switch?
Tried setting the variable of `Radiobutton` to `IntVar` at the end of the loop but it erases the original value that `Radiobutton` had so it's not useful (although it does make them all not switch at once).
What should I do?

```
monokeyholder = IntVar()

for i in range(len(lickey)):

    ttk.Label(mainframe, text=(i + 1)).grid(row=i + 1, column=0)

    ttk.Radiobutton(mainframe, value=1, variable=monokeyholder,
                    command=Sett).grid(row=i + 1, column=1)

    ttk.Radiobutton(mainframe, value=2, variable=monokeyholder,
                    command=Sett).grid(row=i + 1, column=2)

    ttk.Radiobutton(mainframe, value=3, variable=monokeyholder,
                    command=Sett).grid(row=i + 1, column=3)

    ttk.Radiobutton(mainframe, value=4, variable=monokeyholder,
                    command=Sett).grid(row=i + 1, column=4)
```

Is there a way for them to not switch but also hold their value? Should I use different masters maybe or just do 200+ `Radiobutton`s manually (which I doubt is the only way).

Edit: `Sett` is defined to append the value of each selected button to a list. It does work as intended.

Comment: You have to use a different `IntVar` for each set of Radiobuttons.  Create the Var at the top of the loop, and perhaps append it to a list so you can access all the Vars when you want to read the button state.

Comment: alright ill try that.

Comment: @jasonharper i tried this `vardic["mkh" + str(i)] = IntVar()` at the start of the loop but now the value of all sets are 0 except the last set which always has the correct value. weird smh

Comment: Please provide a complete (runnable) [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tkinter uses the variable to know which radiobuttons belong in a set. Threfore, each row needs to use its own instance of `IntVar`. The simplest way to manage them is to store them in a list.

The solution looks something like this:

```
monokeyholder = []
for i in range(len(lickey)):

    var = tk.IntVar(value=0)
    monokeyholder.append(var)
    ...

    ttk.Radiobutton(..., value=1, variable=var, ...)
    ttk.Radiobutton(..., value=2, variable=var, ...)
    ttk.Radiobutton(..., value=3, variable=var, ...)
    ttk.Radiobutton(..., value=4, variable=var, ...)
```

With that, you can get the value for any row with something like this:

```
print(monokeyholder[3].get())
```

Here is a complete working example. When you run it, check any checkboxes you want and the click the "show values" button to see the values.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

def show_values():
    values.delete("1.0", "end")
    for i in range(10):
        values.insert("end", f"Row {i+1}: {monokeyholder[i].get()}\n")

maxrows = 10
mainframe = tk.Frame(root)
showbutton = tk.Button(root, text="Show values", command=show_values)
values = tk.Text(root, height=maxrows, width=20)

showbutton.pack(side="bottom")
mainframe.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)
values.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True)

monokeyholder = []
for i in range(maxrows):

    var = tk.IntVar()
    monokeyholder.append(var)

    ttk.Label(mainframe, text=(i + 1)).grid(row=i, column=0)

    ttk.Radiobutton(mainframe, value=1, variable=var).grid(row=i, column=1)
    ttk.Radiobutton(mainframe, value=2, variable=var).grid(row=i, column=2)
    ttk.Radiobutton(mainframe, value=3, variable=var).grid(row=i, column=3)
    ttk.Radiobutton(mainframe, value=4, variable=var).grid(row=i, column=4)


root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot of example]

Comment: tried this but does not work, the `IntVar` is set and appended before the radiobuttons are even created so the value will always be 0.

Comment: i dont think the variable can be declared inside the loop

Comment: @PEP yes, of course you can create the variable inside the loop. Why do you think you can't? There's nothing special about the `IntVar` class. Python lets you create any sort of object inside a loop.

Comment: @PEP: yes, the value is set to _something_ before you create the radiobuttons. However, once click a radiobutton the value will change. If you later try to print it out, you'll see the correct value. I can guarantee that this works.

Comment: my bad. by can i meant for it to work. when you append the var to the list. only its current value would transfer over to the list so it will always be the the default 0 value.
and yes i tried your solution but did not work unfortunately

Comment: @PEP: no. You're appending the object, not the value. You can always get the current value from the object.

Comment: @PEP: I've added a full working example so you can see that it works.

Comment: thanks for the full code. the problem was that i did not use a loop to get the list values out. that's just my ignorance. thanks!